# Auto-sizing a Shape Assigned as a Graphic to a Cell in JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

At work I created a TableView that needs to have specific cells flash from one color to the other simultaneously. This is relatively easy using Rectangles, FillTransitions, and a ParallelTransition as shown in the toy example below. After assigning the rectangle to the FillTransition, I set the TableCell's graphic to the rectangle. Then I just had to add/remove the FillTransition from the ParallelTransition depending on whether or not the cell should be blinking.

An area where I had a lot of difficulty, however, was in figuring out a way to scale the rectangle to the size of the TableCell containing it as a graphic. The problem I had was that the TableCell would always resize itself to have empty space between its boundaries and the boundaries of the rectangle.

I had to solve this in a very tedious and round-about way: I had to call setFixedCellSize to fix the table's cell height to whatever my rectangle's height was, reposition the rectangle up and to the left by trial and error through calling its setTranslateX/Y, and set the minwidth and minheight of the column to slightly less than whatever my rectangle's width and height was set to. It solved the problem, but I would've hoped for something a little less tedious and annoying.

I would have assumed this could be avoided by doing one or more of the following with the cell:

- Calling setScaleShape(true)
- Calling setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY)
- Setting the cell's CSS style to include "-fx-scale-shape: true"

Sadly, none of these had any noticeable effect...

My question is a three-parter:

1. Is there a better way to size a Shape assigned as a graphic for a Cell to fill the boundaries of the Cell?
2. Why would none of the three methods above have any effect in my case and what is their actual intended purpose? Do they only apply for a shape assigned with setShape() as opposed to setGraphic()?
3. Are there any legitimate reasons why JavaFx wouldn't support setting the preferred width or height of Nodes other than those that subclass Region? Autosizing seems like something that should be universal to all Nodes in the hierarchy, and it seems intuitive that any Parent node should be able to dictate the size of its children when necessary.

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import javafx.animation.Animation;
import javafx.animation.FillTransition;
import javafx.animation.ParallelTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.Border;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderStroke;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderStrokeStyle;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;


public class FlashingPriorityTable extends Application {

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    FlashingPriorityTable.launch();
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    // periodically add prioritized items to an observable list
    final ObservableList<PItem> itemList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    class ItemAdder {
      private int state, count = 0; private final int states = 3;
      public synchronized void addItem() {
        state = count++ % states;
        PItem item;
        if(state == 0)
          item = new PItem(Priority.LOW, count, "bob saget");
        else if(state == 1)
          item = new PItem(Priority.MEDIUM, count, "use the force");
        else
          item = new PItem(Priority.HIGH, count, "one of us is in deep trouble");
        itemList.add(item);
      }
    };
    final ItemAdder itemAdder = new ItemAdder();
    Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1).scheduleAtFixedRate(
        () -> itemAdder.addItem(),
        0, // initial delay
        1, // period
        TimeUnit.SECONDS); // time unit

    // set up a table view bound to the observable list
    final TableColumn<PItem, Priority> priCol = new TableColumn<>("Priority");
    priCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<PItem, Priority>("priority"));
    priCol.setCellFactory((col) -> new PriorityCell()); // create a blinking cell
    priCol.setMinWidth(50);
    priCol.setMaxWidth(50);

    final TableColumn<PItem, Integer> indexCol = new TableColumn<>("Index");
    indexCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<PItem, Integer>("index"));
    indexCol.setCellFactory((col) -> makeBorderedTextCell());

    final TableColumn<PItem, String> descriptionCol = new TableColumn<>("Description");
    descriptionCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<PItem, String>("description"));
    descriptionCol.setCellFactory((col) -> makeBorderedTextCell());
    descriptionCol.setMinWidth(300);

    final TableView<PItem> table = new TableView<>(itemList);
    table.getColumns().setAll(priCol, indexCol, descriptionCol);
    table.setFixedCellSize(25);

    // display the table view
    final Scene scene = new Scene(table);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
  }

  // render a simple cell text and border
  private <T> TableCell<PItem, T> makeBorderedTextCell() {
    return new TableCell<PItem, T>() {
      @Override protected void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if(item == null || empty) {
          setText(null);
        } else {
          setBorder(new Border(new BorderStroke(Color.GREEN, BorderStrokeStyle.SOLID, null, null)));
          setText(item.toString());
        }
      }
    };
  }

  /* for cells labeled as high priority, render an animation that blinks (also include a border) */
  public static class PriorityCell extends TableCell<PItem, Priority> {
    private static final ParallelTransition pt = new ParallelTransition();
    private final Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(49.5, 24);
    private final FillTransition animation = new FillTransition(Duration.millis(100), rect);
    public PriorityCell() {
      rect.setTranslateX(-2.75);
      rect.setTranslateY(-2.7);
      animation.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE); animation.setAutoReverse(true); }
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Priority priority, boolean empty) {
      super.updateItem(priority, empty);
      if(priority == null || empty) {
        setGraphic(null);
        return;
      }
      setGraphic(rect);
      setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
      setBorder(new Border(new BorderStroke(Color.GREEN, BorderStrokeStyle.SOLID, null, null)));
      if(priority == Priority.HIGH) {
        if(!pt.getChildren().contains(animation)) {
          animation.setFromValue(Color.BLACK);
          animation.setToValue(priority.getColor());
          animation.setShape(rect);
          pt.getChildren().add(animation);
          pt.stop(); pt.play();
        }
      } else {
        if(pt.getChildren().contains(animation)) {
          pt.getChildren().remove(animation);
          pt.stop(); pt.play();
        }
        rect.setFill(priority.getColor());
      }
    }
  }

  /* an item that has a priority assigned to it */
  public static class PItem {
    private ObjectProperty<Priority> priority = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
    private IntegerProperty index = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
    private StringProperty description = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public PItem(Priority priority, Integer index, String description) {
      setPriority(priority); setIndex(index); setDescription(description);
    }

    public void setPriority(Priority priority_) { priority.set(priority_); }
    public Priority getPriority() { return priority.get(); }

    public void setIndex(int index_) { index.set(index_); }
    public Integer getIndex() { return index.get(); }

    public void setDescription(String description_) { description.set(description_); }
    public String getDescription() { return description.get(); }
  }

  /* a priority */
  public enum Priority {
    HIGH(Color.RED), MEDIUM(Color.ORANGE), LOW(Color.BLUE);
    private final Color color;
    private Priority(Color color) { this.color = color; }
    public Color getColor() { return color; }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding:

> the TableCell would always resize itself to have empty space between its boundaries and the boundaries of the rectangle.

This is because the cell has by default 2 px of padding, according to modena.css:

```
.table-cell {
    -fx-padding: 0.166667em; /* 2px, plus border adds 1px */
    -fx-cell-size: 2.0em; /* 24 */
}
```

One easy way to get rid of this empty space is just override it:

```
@Override
protected void updateItem(Priority priority, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(priority, empty);
    ...
    setGraphic(rect);
    setStyle("-fx-padding: 0;");
    ...
}
```

The next problem you also mention is autosizing. According to JavaDoc, for `Node.isResizable()`:

> If this method returns true, then the parent will resize the node (ideally within its size range) by calling node.resize(width,height) during the layout pass. All Regions, Controls, and WebView are resizable classes which depend on their parents resizing them during layout once all sizing and CSS styling information has been applied.
>   If this method returns false, then the parent cannot resize it during layout (resize() is a no-op) and it should return its layoutBounds for minimum, preferred, and maximum sizes. Group, Text, and all Shapes are not resizable and hence depend on the application to establish their sizing by setting appropriate properties (e.g. width/height for Rectangle, text on Text, and so on). Non-resizable nodes may still be relocated during layout.

Clearly, a `Rectangle` is not resizable, but this doesn't mean you can't resize it: if the layout doesn't do it for you, you'll need to take care of it.

So one easy solution may be binding the dimensions of the rectangle to those of the cell (minus 2 pixels for the cell borders):

```
private final Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();

@Override
protected void updateItem(Priority priority, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(priority, empty);
    if(priority == null || empty) {
      setGraphic(null);
      return;
    }
    setGraphic(rect);
    setStyle("-fx-padding: 0;");
    rect.widthProperty().bind(widthProperty().subtract(2));
    rect.heightProperty().bind(heightProperty().subtract(2));
    ...
}
```

Note that you won't need to translate the rectangle, and it won't be necessary to fix the size of the cell nor the width of the column, unless you want to give it a fixed size.

Note also that `setShape()` is intended to change the cell shape, that by default is already a rectangle.

This may answer your first two questions. For the third one, sometimes you wish the nodes were always resizable... but if that were the case we will have the opposite problem, trying to keep them constrained...

Comment: Being somewhat new to javafx I was not familiar with modena.css in the slightest before you mentioned it. That is definitely a good file to know about. Just doing what you said absolutely did the trick! Coupled with CSS understanding Javafx is certainly very powerful even if some of the API may seem a bit limited at times! If I don't get another response sometime tomorrow I'll mark yours as the answer.